# Display the value in the alertbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Goal:
Display the value from the input box  to the the alert text popup.

Problem:
Don't know how to do it.

Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        alert("HTML: ");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input value="aaaa" id="asdf" />
<button id="btn2">Show HTML</button>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/oef4o691/2/)

Comment: You have an input element with an id... so use that to get the reference to the input element then use .val() to get its value

Comment: `alert("HTML: " + $("#asdf").val());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#btn2').click(function () {
    var val = $('#asdf').val();
    alert(val);
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9g2emmmy/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use jQuery's [val](https://api.jquery.com/val/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {



  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    alert("HTML: " + $("#asdf").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input value="aaaa" id="asdf" />

<button id="btn2">Show HTML</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the value to the alert using `.val()` and capture the element by id:

```
 alert("HTML: " + $("#asdf").val());
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    
    
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        alert("HTML: " + $("#asdf").val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input value="aaaa" id="asdf" />

<button id="btn2">Show HTML</button>
```